# Entity Framework Fluent, Table-Per-Type performance alternatives

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, fluent

I'm currently working on a EF Fluent project (yes, I do like writing it like that) that is taking a model first approach with Table-Per-Type architecture on EF 4.3.

As I've found out over the past couple of months, Table-Per-Type and inheritance just doesn't play nice -> [more information](http://samscode.com/index.php/2010/01/the-entity-framework-v1-and-v4-deal-breaker-tpt-inheritance/). I'm using a single base class with seven derived classes and just returning items across the seven derived classes isn't particular fast.  In terms of execution timings, to retreive a list of five records EF is taking a between 5 to 7 seconds, subsequent executions are around the 2.5 to 4 second mark.  Safe to say this is just unacceptable so I'm looking at alternative methods...

What I can do is hit the database multiple times, i.e. attempt to retreive each type of object individual and collate into a single collection; however, the code is unwieldly at best, i.e.

```
IList<MyBaseClass> items = new List<MyBaseClass>();

dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<MyFirstDerivedClass>("SELECT * FROM MyBaseClass INNER JOIN MyFirstDerivedClass ON...").ToList().ForEach(x => items.Add(x));

... repeat for each derived class...

return items;
```

But it works!  The first hit on the database takes 2 seconds and subsequent queries a mere 200 milliseconds.

My problem is that this is not very elegant, maintainable, etc, etc.  I have been toying with casting the dbContext into an ObjectContext and running with something like this with a stored procedure ('spGetMyDerivedItems') returning all of the derived resultsets ordered in one db hit...

```
IList<MyBaseClass> items = new List<MyBaseClass>();

ObjectContext oContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

using (var connection = oContext.Connection as EntityConnection)
{
    EntityCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "spGetMyDerivedItems";
    connection.Open();

    using (EntityDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        oContext.Translate<MyFirstDerivedClass>(reader).ToList().ForEach( x => items.Add(x));
        reader.NextResult();
        ...repeat for each derived type...          
    }
}

return items;
```

However, this doesn't work with a InvalidOperationException complaining that the CommandText is not valid and that I must provide a 'ContainerName'.  My guessing here is that if I was using an EDMX file, I could set this set item (and using the DefaultContainerName doesn't work).  But I'm taking a fluent approach and I feel I've hit a dead end.

So...

What approaches are available to resolving the performance problems of EF and table-per-type?
Is it possible to execute a stored procedure through the ObjectContext with Fluent / Model First approach?
Can I execute a standard SQLClient.SqlDataReader and translate into an ObjectContext?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: It's probably not the answer you are looking for, so I leave only a comment and a couple of references here: In EF 5/.NET 4.5 TPT performance has been "significantly improved" according to a statement here: http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015337-tpt-table-per-type-inheritance-performance On the other hand the EF team still discourages the use of TPT here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853.aspx I don't know what the improvement means in seconds or millseconds.

Comment: Generally SQL generation quality and performance (especially due to the default use of complied queries in EF 5/.NET 4.5) has been improved: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/14/sneak-preview-entity-framework-5-0-performance-improvements.aspx and http://www.outofmemory.co.uk/entity-framework-5-dramatically-faster-in-net-4-5/ The improved TPT probably benefits from both.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why not use table-per-inheritance?

Comment: I think .NET 4.5 improvements are mostly based around querying the base type or using `OfType` + autocompiled queries. If you want to query all types the EF has to still generate complex query with lot of joins and performance will be bad.

Comment: Josh - unfortunately I'm picking this project up rather than architecting it up myself.

Slauma - good to hear there's been some improvements, our current development period is going to run with the solution below, but I'll certainly be upgrading!

Comment: @ladislav - good to know.  When I get around to testing EF5 and I'll post up the results (if I remember!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - it appears that the ObjectContext can translate from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader meaning I don't need to derive (directly) from the dbContext.  Here's the example code...

```
IList<MyBaseClass> items = new List<MyBaseClass>();

ObjectContext oContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;

using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(dbContext.Database.Connection.ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand(){
        Connection = sqlConn,
        CommandText = "spGetMyDerivedItems",
        CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    };
    sqlConn.Open();

    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        oContext.Translate<MyFirstDerivedClass>(reader).ToList().ForEach( x => items.Add(x));
        reader.NextResult();
        ...repeat for each derived type...          
    }
}

return items;
```

Obviously the best answer is that EF would pick this up but I'm happy with the above for the moment.  Moving to EF5 sounds like a good move - but with various timescales its better the devil you know :)

Thanks for the help.